# asp.net: how to access to each element of dictionary without using key?

Tags: .net, dictionary, indexing

i want to access each object of my dictionary Dictionary with int index.
hw to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType> myDictionary = . . .


foreach(KeyValuePair<KeyType, ValueType> item in myDictionary)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Key={0}: Value={1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: . . . assuming it's a generic dictionary, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can use a foreach loop as shown below:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("key1", "value2");
dict.Add("key2", "value");
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dict)
   Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "=" + item.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you work from Visual Studio 2008 you might:

```
foreach(var item in myDictionary)
{
   . . . 
}
```

Comment: Noting type of item with be KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> (where myDictionary is IDictionary<TKey, TValue>).

Answer (score 1):

My favourite approach is this one (even though I guess any solution given so far will do the trick for you):

```
// set up the dictionary
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("A key", "Some value");
dictionary.Add("Another key", "Some other value");

// loop over it
Dictionary<string, string>.Enumerator enumerator = dictionary.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.Key + "=" + enumerator.Current.Value);
}
```

Comment: "Foreach" approach is nice and simple, and perhaps is in some way faster dued to compiler optimizations, but the "While" solution is nice if you want a readable way for exit the loop trough a condition, instead of the ugly "exit for" that can be an issue with nested "foreach". So "While" reply has my vote up today :)